# Getting authentication object is null even after successfully login by IDP using SAML

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have configured spring-saml and spring security in my application. I have given different url pattern to recognize request. if I append **/rest** in app URL then it will create spring-security context with basic authentication. If I append **/saml** in app URL then it will populate IDP login page and redirect to index.html after successful login.

But I am getting redirected to login.html page again instead of index.html. After eclipse debugging and putting some logs here and there I got there is no authentication object available.

I have read this [jira link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2027) and updated spring-security version to 3.1.4.RELEASE but it did not solve my issue.

After struggling a lot I find that saml security context is getting cleared by filterChainProxy doFilter method and setting authentication is null and then redirecting to the secured target url which requires authentication which is not present. hence it redirect to login page.

I googled a lot but did not find any way to use saml authentication to pass j_spring_security check.

I have attached my saml-security.xml and spring-security.xml file below

saml-security

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- Unsecured pages -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html"/>
        <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
       <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login.html"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Register authentication manager with SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-manager id="samlAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>


   <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="file:///${user.home}/conf/samlKeyStore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <!-- <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="entityId" value="devenv.abc.com"/>
                <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>






    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="int">500000</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
     </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetailsService" />
    </bean>

     <!-- Custom user details service to attach app specific roles to federated identities -->
    <bean id="samlUserDetailsService" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusSAMLUserDetailsService"/>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="builderFeatures">
            <map>
                <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

And my spring-security.xml file given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> 

    <!-- Definition for logging aspect -->
    <bean id="assumptionAuditLogAspect" class="com.mercatus.audit.AssumptionAuditLogAspect"/> 
    <!-- Definition for project security aspect -->
    <bean id="projectSecurityAspect" class="com.mercatus.web.security.ProjectSecurityAspect"/>
    <!--Definition for SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler  -->
    <bean id="mercatusSavedRequestHandler" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusSavedRequestHandler"/>
    <bean id="mercatusLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <bean id="mercatusAjaxTimeoutFilter" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusAjaxTimeoutFilter"/>


    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </security:http>

    <!-- SAML starts -->
    <security:http pattern="/saml/**" entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/> 
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" /> 
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

     <!-- SAML ends -->

     <security:http pattern="/rest/**"  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="mercatusSavedRequestHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="mercatusAjaxTimeoutFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:http access-denied-page="/login.jsp?login_error=true">
        **<security:intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="ROLE_USER" />**
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/**" access="ROLE_USER" />    
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/customer/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />  
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" authentication-success-handler-ref="mercatusSavedRequestHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/> 
        <security:logout delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
        <security:anonymous />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <oauth2:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth2:authorization-code />
        <oauth2:implicit />
        <oauth2:refresh-token />
        <oauth2:client-credentials />
        <oauth2:password />
    </oauth2:authorization-server>  

    <oauth2:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="mercatus" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

     <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>


     <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider ref="mercatusAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="mercatusAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusAuthenticationProvider" />

</beans>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload the application you're deploying somewhere and post the exact version of Tomcat you're using? I'll try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @VladimírSchäfer I have updated my question with my saml-security and spring-security xml file.

Comment: I am able to login using IDP  with these setting. However I am not able to access any protect resources like index.html shown bold in xml. It redirect me to login page due to intercept url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After struggling for almost a week, finally I have fixed this issue.

While debugging through eclipse I found the root cause inside SAMLAuthenticationProvider there is a method `getEntitlements` which was causing problem.

```
   protected Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getEntitlements(SAMLCredential credential, Object userDetail) {
        if (userDetail instanceof UserDetails) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.addAll(((UserDetails) userDetail).getAuthorities());
            return authorities;
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

Here It is checking whether userDetail object is an instanceOf UserDetails class then return all authority list otherwise empty list of authority will be return.

It is fine with form based authentication which returns `UserDetails` object but If a user logged in through IDP initiated SSO then object of type `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` will be return. Hence It is getting empty list of grantedAuthourity with userDetail object.

So I extends `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` inside my application and override the below method

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getEntitlements(SAMLCredential credential, Object userDetail)
    {
        logger.info("****** object is instance of UserDetails :"+ (userDetail instanceof UserDetails));

        if (userDetail instanceof UserDetails) 
        {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.addAll(((UserDetails) userDetail).getAuthorities());
            return authorities;
        } 
        else if(userDetail instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) 
        {
             List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
             authorities.addAll(((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) userDetail).getAuthorities());
             return authorities;

        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

Then I give my custom authenticationProvider reference into saml-security.xml file with my custom SAMLUserDetailsService class reference.

```
   <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusSAMLAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="samlUserDetailsService" class="com.mercatus.security.MercatusSAMLUserDetailsService"/>
```

The above configuration saved me. I am able to access protected resource after login.

I spent a whole week debugging inside FilterChainProxy, many other filters and here and there because of intercepter URL it was redirecting to FilterChainProxy.

I am posting detailed info because It may be helpful for others who are facing similar issue.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I am facing same issue. The error is like "Authentication object not found in securitycontext". I am implementing Spring Saml integration in my microservice. Can you please provide guidance on the same?

Also it would be helpful if you can provide detail about your custom SAMLUserDetailsService. Thank You.